# heroku finds an old project that i ave deleted on my heroku homepages

Tags: heroku

When I try to disable static files on Heroku it keeps linking to a previous project. However, I deleted all my Heroku projects so there are none in my account.

How is this possible and how do I fix it? The `heroku` CLI seems to be trying to find `vast-depths-55781` but the project I just created is `immense-ridge-40969`:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku determines which app it should use based on your configured Git remotes.

Run `git remote -v` to see which ones you have set up; I suspect you'll see one pointing to `vast-depths-59781`. Remove it by its name, e.g.

```
git remote remove heroku
```

You could manually add a remote for your new app (or have just changed the previous one's URL), but Heroku [provides a dedicated command for setting this up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-heroku-app):

```
heroku git:remote --app immense-ridge-40969
```

Now `heroku` commands should default to the new app in that folder. (You can always provide the `--app` argument to tell `heroku` to operate against a different app if you wish.)